# Set environment variable to output of command in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a file, build-version.txt, that contains the build number "1.2.3". I want to store this build number in an environment variable. In Unix, I would do something like:

```
version=$(cat build-version.txt)
```

How do I do this in Windows? The following doesn't do what I want:

```
set VERSION=type build-version.txt
```

Comment: `for /F %%i in ('echo test') do (echo %%i)` but I am sure this is dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use: `set /P VERSION=< build-version.txt`

and you can check with command: `echo %VERSION%`

Comment: Problem is, this isn't an answer to the question posed in the title, so everyone except OP will waste time with this SO page.